# Solve $t^2y''-2ty'+2y=6t^2+4ln(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that I should find a particular solution, but how ?

I used change of variable method, $t=e^u$ but it didn't work

Comment: This is an Euler equation, it's characteristic polynomial is $r(r-1) -2r+2 =0$

Comment: See :http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx

Comment: Okay, but we should solve for the homogeneous form of the equation first right ?

Comment: Yes... once you find a fundamental set of solutions, you can use something like Variation of Parameters to solve for the inhomogeneous case.

Comment: The fundamental set of solutions should be: $\phi_1(t) = t$ and $\phi_2(t) = t^2$

Comment: Note that for $t >0$, the solutions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are linearly independent, so they form a FSS indeed.

Comment: Thank you , I understood. So now I use variation of parameter right ?

Comment: Yes sir, that's right

Comment: "I used change of variable method, $t=e^u$ but it didn't work". What doesn't work? Please write down what you did.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to try $y=C_1t^2+C_2\log t$.

Comment: @hypernova : That will not work, as $t^2$ is a homogeneous solution, You need then $t^2\ln t$ in the first term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $$x^2y''-2xy'+2y=6x^2+4\ln x.$$

We use change of variable method
$$x=e^t,\quad t=\ln x,\quad \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac1x=e^{-t},$$
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=y_te^{-t},$$
$$y''=\frac{dy'}{dx}=\frac{dy'}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{d(y_te^{-t})}{dt}e^{-t}=(y''_{tt}-y'_t)e^{-2t}$$
Then
$$xy'=y'_t,\quad x^2y''=y''_{tt}-y'_t.$$
We get linear dif. equation with constants coefficients
$$y''_{tt}-3y'_t+2y=6e^{2t}+4t,$$
$$y=y_h+y_p,$$
$$y_h=c_1e^t+c_2e^{2t}$$
With method of undetermined coefficients we find particular solution
$$y_p=Ate^{2t}+Bt+C,\\y_p=6te^{2t}+2t+3.$$
Then general solution is
$$y=c_1e^t+c_2e^{2t}+6te^{2t}+2t+3\\
=c_1x+c_2x^2+6x^2\ln x+2\ln x +3.
$$